# update: getting 400 error 'invalid_payment', only when rides are ordered via api, ordering on phone works fine

Tags: uber-api

I'm getting an "invalid_payment" error only when ordering rides via the api. I thought it may have been an account issue so checked my app but I was able to login and order manually on my phone without any problems.

Here is my request and response. Is there anything else you need?

Request:

```
curl -X POST \

  https://api.uber.com/v1/requests \
  -H 'authorization: Bearer TOKEN' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'content-type: application/json' \
  -H 'postman-token: c2e706c0-5bde-c324-1326-8bfc43a37079' \
  -d '{
    "start_latitude": "43.854816",
    "start_longitude": "-79.4368132",
    "start_address": "9350 Yonge Street, Richmond Hill, ON L4C 5G2",
    "product_id": "d1e548ac-4be5-46c0-8c86-201ac8a36fc6",
    "end_latitude":"43.8656588",
    "end_longitude":"-79.4411572",
    "end_address": "11 Bingham Street, Richmond Hill, ON L4C 8Y6"
}'
```

Response:

```
{"meta":{},"errors":[{"status":400,"code":"invalid_payment","title":"The rider's payment method is invalid and they must update their billing info."}]}
```

Edit: When ordered via the API the request does not come up like it usually does when you have the app on your phone open. Additionally, the API is letting me order rides normally for some addresses, just not all (mainly Canadian) addresses.

Edit 2: I tried refreshing the token thinking it may have been a caching issue but no luck.

Edit 3: This appears to really only be happening for addresses in Canada. API can order rides successfully without invalid_payment error in the U.S.

Comment: Have you found the solution for this?

Comment: No, and it got worse to no longer just be Canadian rides. We eventually had to stop using the API.